# Is it risky to parse JSON string from websockets?

Tags: javascript, json, security, websocket, xss

I'm writing an Angular2 web application, and I want bidirectional communication with the server, so the perfect solution is with websockets.

Mozilla fundation [teaches](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API/Writing_WebSocket_client_applications) to use `JSON.stringify(msg)` to parse a string that represents a JSON message, both for sending and receiving data with websocket. This leads to some thoughts on injection. For example, suppose the following JSON document being transfered from the server to the client's machine:

```
{
  message{
    from: "paul",
    text:"hello!",
    date:"01/01/2017"
  }
}
```

Now suppose paul changes his name to `"paul\"` and sends the following text:

```
,text: alert('xss'),something:"
```

then the following JSON received by the client would be:

```
{
  message{
    from: "paul\",
    text:",text: alert('xss'),something:"",
    date:"01/01/2017"
  }
}
```

which is, in fact, the following JSON (just rearranged):

```
{
  message{
    from: "paul\",text:",
    text: alert('xss'),
    something:"",
    date:"01/01/2017"
  }
}
```

which could cause problems, depending on what is done with this JSON, I guess. Is there some way to prevent these things, or is the JSON.stringfy technique safe because when inserting data from the JSON into the DOM, the text attribute would be undefined because alert('xss') is not a string (or does not return anything)?

Also, see that if there's no problem with calling a function like alert(), we were able to set the `something` variable to anything we wanted, this is for sure risky.

Comment: JSON can not contain functions, so it is safe - your assertion that JSON received by client could contain `text: alert('xss')` is erroneous

Comment: @JaromandaX ok, but ignore the alert and se that I was able to set the something attribute with the injection also

Comment: `ignore the alert` ... OK, so what's the problem if JSON can't contain functions ... you used `alert` as an example function, as did I ... the spec for JSON isn't `it can contain any function except alert` it is `it can not contain any functions`

Comment: @Gatonito Setting some attribute isn't going to matter either, if your client never uses it. Just use an https connection and this issue pretty much vaporizes.

Comment: Setting the `something` attribute is the same as setting the `from` attribute, or any other "attribute", those are really only keys in your JSON, and you can set whatever you want without it being an issue ?

Comment: @adeneo the problem is that it could mean something... I don't want to leave room for possibilities. The something variable could be used for like... Setting text in the DOM to trick the user, or change important values from the message like date, or whatever.

Comment: @JaromandaX also, if alert('xss') is a problem, "alert('xss')" would be acceptable, and if that is inserted into the DOM, it would be a problem

Comment: Unless you're the one who's eval'ing or inserting the values from the JSON, it's not possible for anyone else to "set" anything, and you should never trust the user, and validate the user data before you use it, always.

Comment: `and if that is inserted into the DOM` - why would you "insert JSON into the DOM" ... JSON has nothing to do with the DOM

Comment: `the problem is that it could mean something` - yes, it's a key in an object - that's all it means

Comment: @JaromandaX the text in the JSON is supposed to be inserted in the page for the user to read

Comment: @Gatonito - your `code` would do that - so don't write stupid code :p

Comment: @JaromandaX so I shouldn't insert a message in the DOM? How would the user read it?

Comment: I never said that.

Comment: adding **text** to the DOM is never risky

Comment: most easy ways of converting json to html, like mustache.js, default to escaping potentially harmful HTML content. If the JSON is mal-formed, it won't parse, unlike say an SQL statement, where simply matching up the right/wrong string chars can cause interpretation issues. In short, there's nothing risky about json itself.